# DropDownListFor not populating selected value

Tags: razor, model-view-controller, dropdownlistfor

Probably a frequently asked question, but I didn't found any answer matching my problem.

I got a SelectList like, which I want to show in a DropDown:

```
var selectList = new SelectList(listItems, "Text", "Value", selectedCustomer);

 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Name, selectList, "-- Select Customer --")
```

The list holds the correct values, one is selected. But the dropdownlist shows only the text "-- Select Customer --".

**Populating listItems:**

```
List<SelectListItem> listItems = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (Customer c in Model.GetAllCustomer())
{
    listItems.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = c.Id, Value = c.Name });
}
```

**To clarify my question:** The dropdown works fine on most sites (it's in the layout page). But sometimes after a POST request it does not show any selected value. All the provided code is in the layout page.

Comment: Can you please show the code for populating `listItems`?

Comment: Is "selectList" Populated? Did you check using debug mode? how to you transfer "listItems" to the view? how is your entity looks like? show more code please..